# Independent contractor taxes with J1 visa

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, foreign-income

I have a J-1 visa as Research Scholar to pursue full-time research at an American university.

The visa is sponsored by the university and expires on June 2023.
I am planning to move back to Europe when my visa expires. I am a European citizen.

I have received a part-time consulting job offer from a European company. According to the consulting agreement, I will not be an employee of the company, but I will work as an independent contractor.

I will get compensation for this consulting activity from April - June 2023 while living in the US.

Should I pay taxes for the April-June compensation in the US? What do you suggest to do?

Answer (score 4):

> Should I pay taxes for the April-June compensation in the US?

Of course. This is US-sourced income that is not related to your J-1 job. It doesn't matter where the employer is, what matters is where *you* are.

> What do you suggest to do?

Not do this. I don't know how much you'd be earning, but is it worth committing an immigration offense that can potentially bar you from ever entering or living in the US?

Comment: no wait - I want to pay taxes and do everything legally. Since the company is not US based, I was wondering whether there are special legal loopholes. That's all, really.

Comment: @apt45 the company is fine, they're not breaking any laws. It's you who are not allowed to work in the US outside your J1 position.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!